# JT400 send a message to a queue (I.e. SNDMSG)

Tags: ibm-midrange, jt400

Is this the only option when using jt400 to send a message to a queue?

```
sys = AS400("~")
cmd = CommandCall(sys)
cmd.run("SNDMSG 'My Message'")
```

The `MessageQueue` api does not appear to have any sort of `send` or `write` method.

[CommandCall](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzahh/javadoc/com/ibm/as400/access/CommandCall.html)

[MessageQueue](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzahh/javadoc/com/ibm/as400/access/MessageQueue.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take look at the sendXXX() methods of MessageQueue in the documentation you provided a link to...

[image: sendXxxx() methods]

Comment: Wow this is one of those clearing the fog off the window type of deals. I don't know why but I read over the MessageQueue methods like 3 times and the whole "informational"/"inquiry" words just immediately switched my brain into "that's not it" mode.